# Can't refresh Windows RT on Surface

Tags: microsoft-surface, windows-rt, windows-8-refresh

When I try to refresh my Surface RT tablet it comes up with the error message "The media you have inserted is not valid" Please Insert your windows installation or recovery media. I have done this as I deleted my recovery partition and I would like to reinstall.

I need help desperately as it is my computer that I use everyday.

Comment: The recovery partition was where the recovery image was stored. I don't think either Refresh or Reset will work for you now, and since there's no other way to install WinRT you might not have any option open to you but to contact MS and see what they have to say about it.